# Summary of Dirichlet Series Convergence from Apostol's IANT

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

I've been trying to learn about Dirichlet series, in particular from Apostol's IANT textbook.

The textbooks tend to present result and not discuss them narratively, so I am left unsure of my correct understandanding of the results.

Are the following summary statements a correct interpretation of Apostol's IANT:

1. If a Dirichlet series $\sum_{n \leq x} a_n/n^s$ is **bounded** at complex $s_0=\sigma_0+it_0$ then it is also **bounded** at $s_1=\sigma_1+it_1$ where $\sigma_1>\sigma_0$.
2. If a Dirichlet series $\sum_{n \leq x} a_n/n^s$ is **bounded** at complex $s_0=\sigma_0+it_0$ then it also **converges** when $x\rightarrow \infty$ at $s_1=\sigma_1+it_1$ where $\sigma_1>\sigma_0$.
3. If $\sum_{n \leq x} a_n$ is bounded, then the Dirichlet series $\sum a_n/n^s$ converges for $\sigma>0$.

Comment: They all are correct and follow from summation by parts and the properties oh $n^{-s}$ - for $s=\sigma$ it is just summation by parts but then one has to take care of the oscillation